# How to return data to Jquery.Get request from php Method in formated method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Just moved from Asp.net to php.

i am following some tutorial related php mvc.

The problem i am currently facing is returning data to ajax call. The data is coming but dashboard view is also attached to it.

My route is setted as:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am making jquery request as

```
$.get('http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/dashboard/xhrGetListItem',function(o){
       console.log(o);
    });
```

response is in this way:

```
[{"id":"1","text":"hassaan khan"},{"id":"2","text":"we are working fine by the way and all is good hope you all are good too"},{"id":"3","text":"\r\n    how day how days are going hope you all working fine"},{"id":"4","text":"\r\n    how day how days are going hope you all working fine"},{"id":"5","text":"i am doing some thing extremely good. know that\r\ni am working on php.\r\n    "}]
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/public/css/default.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/public/js/custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/views/dashboard/js/default.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
         //Custom Functions here
        })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        Header

            <br />
            <a href="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/index">Index</a>
            <a href="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/help">Help</a>
            <a href="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/dashboard/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        Content



dashboard ... logged in


            <br/>
            <form id="dashForm" action="http://localhost:44500/phpmvc/dashboard/xhrInsert" method="post">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="text"></textarea>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <hr/>
            <div id="listInsert"></div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="footer">
    &copy; Footer
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**As you can see Dashboard page/view html is also returning in data success**

I have set up Dashboard controller function as:

```
 function xhrGetListItem(){
    //$this->model Dashboard Model object initialized in constructor
    //calling model method 
    $this->model->xhrGetListComment();
    }
```

And inside Dashboard Model I have method definition

```
function xhrGetListComment(){
        //$this->db get the database object
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM data');
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
        $sth->execute();  
        $data = $sth->fetchAll();
        //print(json_encode($data));
        echo json_encode($data);            
    }
```

**How do i only return json object?**

Comment: Probably not the cleanest way if some prossecing needs to be done afterwards, but works when there isn't : add `exit();` after you echo the JSON data. Otherwise, you might be interested in [ob_end_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) or something close to it, to "end" the output. And be careful if you use it : _"The output buffer must be started by ob_start()"_ (before you start echoing anything).

Comment: @blex exit() works. I need to close the connection and finalize the response. Thanks mate